# Why am I getting a SyntaxError on a type annotation?

Tags: python, atom-editor

I have code and error below in screenshot. But not sure why it is giving me this error. Please kindly help.

```
def add_node(self, id: str, name: str) -> None:
    """
    add a tuple (id, name) representing a node to self.nodes if it does not already exist
    The graph should not contain any duplicate nodes
    """
    node = (id, name)
    if node not in self.nodes:
        self.nodes.append(node)
    return self.nodes
```

[image: Screenshot for code and error]

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  Type annotations were introduced in Python 3, but with an old interpreter might give you an error like that.

Comment: That's valid Python, and works on my machine just fine. Is this in some 3rd party IDE that doesn't allow you to use type hints?

Comment: Seems like your editor is running with Python 2 (or really old Python 3). There's nothing wrong with this in Python 3. So you need to update your editor to run it with the correct version.

Comment: @Daniel From the tags, it looks like OP's using Atom, and that output pane looks like the `script` package, which uses an external interpreter.

Comment: The Python 2 issue is on the money. I'm relatively new to Python, and keep forgetting that Python 2 is a thing.

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). By the way, this is totally off-topic, but why are you using a non-monospace font for code editing?

Comment: interesting choice of font...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the [`script`](https://atom.io/packages/script) package and it's using Python 2 (since [function annotations were added in Python 3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/)). If so, I bet the problem is a missing shebang or bad shebang. Try adding this to the top of your Python file:

```
#/usr/bin/env python3
```

Explanation:

- If the shebang is missing, `script` will default to the program called `python` (based on the [grammar](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/grammar/) selected), which I believe is still Python 2 on macOS.
- If the shebang just says `python`, same thing: it'll use the system version
- If the shebang says `python2`, there's your problem

Comment: If this were the problem, then surely the traceback would have reported an error earlier than line 58.

Comment: @John Well, there's no [mre], so we have no way of knowing. For all we know, there could be 57 lines of comments then the function definition.

Comment: This works for me! Thank you so much!