# How to start permanently a remote process from and via Python utilising ssh?

Tags: python, ssh, raspberry-pi, subprocess

I would like to start from a python program another python "Server.py" program on a remote machine via ssh.

The program is starting locally in a bash shell via:

```
    nohup ./Server.py 1>Server.log 2>&1 &
```

without any problem. To be complete, Server.log shows (2nd line is the used interpreter version):

```
    nohup: ignoring input
```

and process is running properly even if I close the bash-shell:

```
   pi       26119     1  0 20:15 ?        00:00:00 /home/pi/.pyenv/versions/3.11.4/bin/python ./Server.py
```

If I try to start it remotely via:

```
    cmd = ["ssh", target, "nohup "+ Conf.FILES[0] + " 1>./Server.log 2>&1 &"]
    print("cmd=", cmd)
    try:
       result = subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True, check=True, text=True).stdout[:-1]
```

the remote process starts with the print statement equals to:

```
    cmd= ['ssh', '<MyInternetServerName>', 'nohup ./Server.py 1>./Server.log 2&1 &']
```

but I get an unexpected Python error (in Server.log):

```
    File "./Server.py", line 102
       def handle_client(self, connfd: socket.socket):
                                     ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I thought, that I'm doing the same thing, but I recognised different Python versions being used for execution. Locally by bash and remotely by ssh calls on the same machine (a big THANKS to the initial answers, which gave me a hint where to look at).
I couldn't solve it so far, but I need to investigate further and update this Question accordingly.

Comment: Looks like an older Python version is used. Check the shebang of your script.

Comment: shebang is the same for local and remote call.
However different python versions are called.
Strange, need to check this. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69230894/why-am-i-getting-a-syntaxerror-on-a-type-annotation) question.

It seems like you are Python 2. Make sure to enforce Python 3 when running your script. i. e adding this to the top of your script:

```
#/usr/bin/env python3
```

Comment: shebang looks ok. However different python versions are called.
Strange, need to check this. Thanks for the hint.